# Call function from render method one time (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

In this test code:

```
 @Override
    public void render() {
        test();
    }

    private void test() {
    }
```

How can I call `test();` one time (NOT loop) ?

Comment: boolean a=true;
public void render(){
if(a)
{
test():
a=false:
}

Comment: You should add more of your code.  At least show what class this is and what it's extending.

Comment: ya.. i got it. but i want to make switch on this method one time then switch off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is simple flag. Just create a **boolean** that will tell you if test() was called

```
    boolean isTestCalled = false;

    private void test()
    {
        System.out.println("test!");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        if( !isTestCalled )
        {
            isTestCalled = true;
            test();
        }

        ...
```

you can change **boolean** to int and increase it every time you will call test() to limit test call count. I don't very like flags - it generates **spaghetti code**.

---

If it would be C++ the second option would be using **static variable** inside test function and just tell it how many times it should be called - **but hey this is Java :)**. Statics are only for classes but you still can simulate it:

```
    //even inside your class
    static class Counter
    {
        public static int count = 0;
    }

    private void test(int limit)
    {
        if( ++Counter.count <= limit ) //here you can add something like ...&& limit > 0 to have and option to infinite calls when calling test(-1) for example
        {   
            System.out.println("test!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        test(2);

        ...
```

---

And last but not least - in case you want to call **test()** exactly on a start of render - just move it to the **show()** function. But I guess it is not what you want to do when you are creating a question like this.